# Difficulties running the Hybris storefront, and WCMS in Live Edit.. produces Tomcat exception

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am getting the same problem in the Hybris accelerator storefront, and in Hybris WCMS Live Edit view:

a. When I run https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/en/

b. Hybris returns the following message from Apache Tomcat [See Appendix]

c. Any suggestions?

====

APPPENDIX

> type Exception report
>
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /WEB-INF/views/desktop/pages/layout/landingLayout2Page.jsp at line 6
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /WEB-INF/views/desktop/pages/layout/landingLayout2Page.jsp at
>   line 6
>
> 3: <%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/cmstags" %> 4:
>   <%@ taglib prefix="common" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common" %> 5:
>   6:  7:     8:        9:
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:256)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:345)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.btg.BTGSegmentFilter.doFilterInternal(BTGSegmentFilter.java:47)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.CartRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CartRestorationFilter.java:122)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AnonymousCheckoutFilter.doFilterInternal(AnonymousCheckoutFilter.java:39)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:77)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:81)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:101)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:79)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230)
>   .... ....
>
> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.59 log

Comment: Is this an out of the box install? What ECP version? Do you have any custom add ons installed into the storefront?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps given below:

1. Add the liveeditaddon AddOn to your localextensions.xml file, ensuring the listed required extensions are also included.

   a. liveeditaddon b. addonsupport c. cmscockpit

These extensions are normally already included in the localextensions.xml file. If this is the case, you can ignore this step.

2. Call the addoninstall ant command, as follows:

   ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="liveeditaddon" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="yacceleratorstorefront"

This generates the correct properties in the project.properties file of the liveeditaddon AddOn and adds a dependency from your storefront to the liveeditaddon AddOn.

3. Add the following properties to your local.properties file:

   cmsPageBeforeViewHandler=com.hybris.storefront.interceptors.beforeview.CmsPageBeforeViewHandler
   uiThemeResourceBeforeViewHandler=com.hybris.storefront.interceptors.beforeview.UiThemeResourceBeforeViewHandler
4. Rebuild the hybris system by running ant clean all from the hybris/bin/platform directory.